# weird behaviour with protected static properties and inheritance in php

Tags: php, static, visibility

I have a problem with static members and inheritance in php

Why this works:

```
class A {
   public static function me() {
     echo static::$b;
   }
}

class B extends A
{
 protected static $b = "hello";
}
B::me();
```

and this not??????????:

```
class A {
   public static function me() {
     echo static::$b;
   }
}

class B extends A
{
 private static $b = "hello";
}
B::me();
```

I understand that I'm referring to variable $b from A context 
but why can I access protected member and not the private one?
Thank you.

Comment: could you add a little more please. Is it a question of you not understanding the difference or about errors? If it's the latter, please post more details

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0):

Look. `private` is meant only for the class itself, while `protected` is for the family. No wonder $b is not accessible in A if you declare it `private` for B, no matter B inherits from A. On the other hand if you declare it `protected`, A can also access it because it belongs to B's family.

Comment: I don't think so...PHP doc says:
"Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited classes". It says inherited and not parent class

Comment: Your `static::$b` is a late static binding (look up in phpdoc). The visibility concept is that something set as protected static will ensure the member variable can only be accessed in the super class _or_ derived classes.

Comment: I perfectly know what is late static binding...hence if it is like you saying I have to assume that the php doc about protected member is not quite correct?

Comment: Sorry that I cannot tell. All I am saying is that `protected static` does not have the instance level visibility rules. Static is stored and accessed at class level, with the above visibility rules. Without the late binding I doubt you would manage to reference the non-existent $b in A. Give it a try, I am curious myself...

Comment: Well...If we move to not static context we have the same problem:
class A
{
   public function test() {
     echo $this->b;
   }

}


class B extends A
{
  protected $b = "hello";
}

$a = new B();
$a->test();

I think this does not make sense...How a parent can access a protected child member, if (like they say in php doc) "Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited classes"?